# UIStackView spacing not working for nested stack views with baseline alignment

Tags: swift, nested, alignment, uistackview, spacing

I'm attempting to include a series of UITextFields, with corresponding UILabels, in a vertical UIStackView.  I'm nesting each label/field pair in a horizontal UIStackView, and the width of the labels is hard-coded to the widest intrinsic width of all the labels, so that they line up nicely.

It very nearly works, but the horizontal stack views are not spaced evenly as expected (spacing = 5) and are bunched up and overlapping.

HOWVER, if I delete the line `hFieldStack.alignment = .lastBaseline`, then it all works perfectly.

I'm OK with deleting that line, as it looks fine.  But I'm just curious as to why spacing in the outside stack view doesn't work when using lastBaseline alignment within the nested stack view.

[image: stack view spacing issue]

```
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        stackView.spacing = 5
        stackView.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        stackView.isLayoutMarginsRelativeArrangement = true

        if let titleLabel = titleLabel {
            stackView.addArrangedSubview(titleLabel)
        }
        
        if let messageLabel = messageLabel {
            stackView.addArrangedSubview(messageLabel)
        }
        
        if textFields.count == fieldLabels.count {
            for i in 0..<textFields.count {
                fieldLabels[i].widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
                let hFieldStack = UIStackView()
                hFieldStack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
                hFieldStack.axis = .horizontal
                hFieldStack.alignment = .lastBaseline
                hFieldStack.spacing = 5
                hFieldStack.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 10, bottom: 0, right: 10)
                hFieldStack.isLayoutMarginsRelativeArrangement = true
                hFieldStack.addArrangedSubview(fieldLabels[i])
                hFieldStack.addArrangedSubview(textFields[i])
                stackView.addArrangedSubview(hFieldStack)
            }
        } else {
            logger.error("Field count doesn't match label count")
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Curious...

It appears that, when setting the horizontal stack view's Alignment to `.lastBaseline` (also happens with `.firstBaseline`), Auto-layout is using the text field's ***`_UITextFieldCanvasView`*** to calculate the layout.

So, with a rounded-rect border, the actual frame of the text field is **taller** than the `_UITextFieldCanvasView`.

We can confirm this by inspecting the view hierarchy:

[image]

The labels are nicely **baseline aligned** with the text rendered in the `_UITextFieldCanvasView`... but the frames are obviously extending outside the stack view's framing.

While the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistackview/alignment) do list `.lastBaseline` as. valid Alignment constant, it's somewhat telling that, in Storyboard / Interface Builder, the only Alignment options are `Fill`, `Leading`, `Center` and `Trailing`.

I've come across several actual **Bugs** related to StackViews --- so I think I would (personally) add this one to the list.